# Python elasticsearch DSL aggregation/metric of nested values per document

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm trying to find the minimum (smallest) value in a 2-level nesting (separate minimum value per document).

So far I'm able to make an aggregation which counts the min value from all the nested values in my search results but without separation per document.

My example schema:

```
class MyExample(DocType):
    myexample_id = Integer()
    nested1 = Nested(
        properties={
            'timestamp': Date(),
            'foo': Nested(
                properties={
                    'bar': Float(),
                }
            )
        }
    )
    nested2 = Nested(
        multi=False,
        properties={
            'x': String(),
            'y': String(),
        }
    )
```

And this is how I'm searching and aggregating:

```
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, Q

search = Search().filter(
    'nested', path='nested1', inner_hits={},
    query=Q(
        'range', **{
            'nested1.timestamp': {
                'gte': exampleDate1,
                'lte': exampleDate2
            }
        }
    )
).filter(
    'nested', path='nested2', inner_hits={'name': 'x'},
    query=Q(
        'term', **{
            'nested2.x': x
        }
    )
).filter(
    'nested', path='nested2', inner_hits={'name': 'y'},
    query=Q(
        'term', **{
            'nested2.y': y
        }
    )
)

search.aggs.bucket(
    'nested1', 'nested', path='nested1'
).bucket(
    'nested_foo', 'nested', path='nested1.foo'
).metric(
    'min_bar', 'min', field='nested1.foo.bar'
)
```

Basically what I need to do is to get the min value for all the nested nested1.foo.bar values for each unique MyExample (they have unique myexample_id field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want minimum value per document then put all the `nested` buckets within a bucket `terms` aggregation over `myexample_id` field:

```
search.aggs..bucket(
  'docs', 'terms', field='myexample_id'
).bucket(
  'nested1', 'nested', path='nested1'
).bucket(
  'nested_foo', 'nested', path='nested1.foo'
).metric(
  'min_bar', 'min', field='nested1.foo.bar'
)
```

Note that this aggregation might be extremely expensive to calculate since it has to create a bucket for each document. For a use case like this it might be easier to compute the minimum on a per document basis as a `script_field` or in the app.

Comment: I was even going to suggest that this minimum value should be figured out at indexing time and stored at the root level of the document. It would make the whole thing a lot more performant than several levels of aggs on `nested` documents or using scripting.